# Shifting x axis in dataframe.plot() : Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

Hey I have a dataframe in python that has the index set as a datetime, 3 columns with integer values, a column with some decimals and a column that is a moving average.

```
min_date    Full_Name        Quotes     Ratio          MA
2019-10-14  Melissa Felix       2  ...  1.000000       NaN
2019-10-15  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.000000       NaN
2019-10-16  Melissa Felix       4  ...  0.750000       NaN
2019-10-17  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.666667       NaN
2019-10-21  Melissa Felix       2  ...  1.000000       NaN
2019-10-22  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.666667       NaN
2019-10-23  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.000000       NaN
2019-10-24  Melissa Felix       6  ...  0.333333       NaN
2019-10-25  Melissa Felix       4  ...  0.750000       NaN
2019-10-28  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.333333  0.550000
2019-10-29  Melissa Felix       5  ...  0.400000  0.490000
2019-10-30  Melissa Felix       3  ...  1.000000  0.590000
2019-11-07  Melissa Felix       5  ...  0.400000  0.555000
2019-11-08  Melissa Felix       5  ...  0.000000  0.488333
2019-11-09  Melissa Felix       7  ...  0.285714  0.416905
2019-11-14  Melissa Felix       2  ...  0.500000  0.400238
2019-11-15  Melissa Felix       1  ...  0.000000  0.400238
2019-11-18  Melissa Felix       7  ...  0.428571  0.409762
2019-11-19  Melissa Felix       4  ...  0.250000  0.359762
2019-11-20  Melissa Felix       4  ...  0.000000  0.326429
2019-11-21  Melissa Felix       2  ...  0.500000  0.336429
2019-11-26  Melissa Felix       3  ...  0.000000  0.236429
2019-11-27  Melissa Felix       2  ...  0.000000  0.196429
2019-11-29  Melissa Felix       4  ...  0.000000  0.196429
```

When I simply plot the moving average with 
`mra2['MA'].plot()` I get the following:

[image: plot]

I would like, however, for the x-axis to be shifted by 2 days so that the x-labels are 2019-10-13,2019-10-20,2019-10-27, etc. The data will be refreshed every week so how can I make it so the x axis is always falling into this sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `matplotlib.dates.WeekdatLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = mra2['MA'].plot()
ax.set_xlim(left=pd.to_datetime('2019-10-13'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=mdates.SU))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically? The dataframe is going to be refreshed on a weekly basis. So next week 2019-10-13 would not longer be in the dataframe and the end date would be + 1 week. Essentially, the dataframe is going to represent data within the period of getdate() - 5 weeks. How can I do this so I don't have to manually changed the start_date and end_date, if possible?

Comment: You don’t really need `ax.set_lim`.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that you can always mask your datetime like this:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 13)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29)

mask = (mra2['min_date'] >= start_date) & (mra2['min_date'] <= end_date)
new_mra2= mra2.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
plt.plot(new_mra2['min_date'], new_mra2['MA'])
```

If you want to do this dynamically, e.g. you want to have a 5 weeks interval, you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=35)
end_date = datetime.today()

mask = (mra2['min_date'] >= start_date) & (mra2['min_date'] <= end_date)
new_mra2= mra2.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
plt.plot(new_mra2['min_date'], new_mra2['MA'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically? The dataframe is going to be refreshed on a weekly basis. So next week 2019-10-13 would not longer be in the dataframe and the end date would be + 1 week. Essentially, the dataframe is going to represent data within the period of getdate() - 5 weeks. How can I do this so I don't have to manually changed the start_date and end_date, if possible?

Comment: @JustinRivera, Of course, you can do this. I have modified my code. Hope this helps.